# Can not import python modules from package

Tags: python, import, package

My project path is like:

```
main.py
modules/
     __init__.py
     databaseManager.py
     sync.py
     excel.py
```

in main.py:

```
from modules.databaseManger import addExcelToDb, searchInDbAll
from modules.excel import search, showExcelDirContents
from modules.sync import syncExcelAndDB
```

and for example in database.py :

```
from modules.excel import showExcelDirContents
from modules.sync import insertExcelNameToSyncDb
```

but when I run main.py I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
   from modules.databaseManger import searchIn
ImportError: cannot import name 'searchInDbAll'
```

and also having error when trying to import a function from each file in modules directory to others.

I need some examples of `import`ing.

Comment: from operator import itemgetter
from urllib.parse import parse_qsl
from time import time

Comment: `from modules.databaseManger import addExcelToDb, searchInDbAll`: what / where is `databaseManger`? (also, note you have a typo)

Comment: this is a mistake i correct it but also have a problem

Comment: @HasanKho please specify your version of Python

Comment: @andriy-maletsky Python 3.6.5

Comment: No need to add "solved" in a title: instead, mark an answer as accepted using the green checkmark. Or post your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **circular import** issue.

**Explanation:**

You start by triggering import of `databaseManager` module.

During this `databaseManager` code starts to import `excel`.

During `excel` importing, `excel` code tries to retrieve function `searchInDbAll()` from `databaseManager`. But at that moment this function does not exist - because `databaseManager` is in process of importing `excel` and he hasn't started defining any functions.

**How to fix:**

In modules where circular import conflicts exist, import modules instead of functions. For example, change this:

```
from modules.excel import showExcelDirContents
```

to that:

```
from modules import excel
```

And of course, you must then change corresponding function calls, from `showExcelDirContents()` to `excel.showExcelDirContents()`.

You must do this in your `databaseManger`, `excel` and `sync` modules. With this fix, I actually could run your code.

And yeah, remove appends to sys.path, that is wrong

Comment: thank you so much , that problem solved .Andriy Maletsky

Answer (score 0):

You can append to your path where you put your modules like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('modules/')
```

or

```
import sys
sys.path.append('c:/mycode/stuff/modules/')
```

**note** those are forward slashes, or you can use double backslashes like \\

Then just have your databaseManger.py file in /modules

You'll also need to have a file in the /modules folder named:

```
__init__.py
```

Which is just an empty file

Then you should be able to do:

`from databaseManger import addExcelToDb, searchInDbAll`

Comment: i added __init__.py and i tried both sys.path.append(path) but also , same error apears

Comment: @HasanKho for the path you need to use forward slashes like `/` or double backslashes since backslash is an escape character

Comment: how about modules files ? i should write path method in them too ?   now just modules files error . for example how should i import database Manager  methods in excel ? i do : from .database import (methods) but i get error

Comment: I don't think you need to unless those files also need to import from your 'modules' folder too